# receiving data from web server doesn't work (volley library android)

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

For fetch data I use volley library. When i use Local Address everything work right. My activity shows data.

```
String json_url = "http://192.168.1.4/android/contactinfo.php";
```

but when I fetch data from Web server (internet) my activity doesn't show anything, so it is empty without any error

```
 String json_url = "http://www.viratebco.com/phpme/3/1.php";
```

I compared the output of these two pages and they were exactly like each other.
this is my php code

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    @ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $pwd="";
    $db="android";
    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$pwd,$db) or die ('unable to connect');
   mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM imageactor";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($response,array("Name"=>$row["name"],"Pic"=>$row["pic"],"Description"=>$row["description"]));

}
header("Connection: Keep-alive");
header("Content-length: 468");
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

and this is my class for fetch data of server

```
   public class BackgrundTask {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Contact_actors_list> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    String json_url = "http://192.168.1.4/phpme/3/1.php";


    public BackgrundTask (Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public ArrayList<Contact_actors_list> getList()
    {


        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, json_url,(String) null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("TAG67", response.toString());
                        int count = 0;
                        while (count<response.length())
                        {
                            try {
                              //  Log.d("TAG67", "kk"+count);

                                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
                             //   Log.d("TAG67", "Pic "+jsonObject.getString("Pic"));
                            //    Log.d("TAG67", "Description "+jsonObject.getString("Description"));
                            //    Log.d("TAG67", "Name "+jsonObject.getString("Name"));
                                Contact_actors_list contact_actors_list = new Contact_actors_list(jsonObject.getString("Name"),jsonObject.getString("Pic"),jsonObject.getString("Description"));
                                Log.d("TssssssssAG67", contact_actors_list.getDescription());
                                arrayList.add(contact_actors_list);
                                count++;

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("tageiu", "Error at sign in : " + e.getMessage());


                            }
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("ERtROR123", "Error123 "+ error.getMessage());
                Log.d("ERtROR123", "Error123 "+ error.getMessage());
            }

        }

        );
        int x=4;// retry count
        jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 48,
                x, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        MySingleton.getmInstance(context).addToRequestque(jsonArrayRequest);
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

My MySingleton class

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static Context mCtx;
    private MySingleton(Context context){
        mCtx = context;
        requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue()
    {
        if (requestQueue==null)
        {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return  requestQueue;
    }
    public static synchronized MySingleton getmInstance(Context context)
    {
        if (mInstance == null)
        {
            mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestque(Request<T> request)
    {
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, -1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }


}
```

My actorList Page

```
public class actorsList extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<Contact_actors_list> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actors_list);
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(actorsList.this, recyclerView ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(actorsList.this, DetailsAsctor.class);
                        Contact_actors_list pp = arrayList.get(position);
                        intent.putExtra("pic", pp.getPic());
                        intent.putExtra("title", pp.getName());
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //Toast.makeText(actorsList.this,position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(actorsList.this,"click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
        );
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        BackgrundTask backgroundTask = new BackgrundTask(actorsList.this);
        arrayList = backgroundTask.getList();
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapterActorsList(arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

RecyclerAdapterActorsList

```
public class RecyclerAdapterActorsList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterActorsList.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Contact_actors_list> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public  RecyclerAdapterActorsList(ArrayList<Contact_actors_list> arrayList)
    {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item_actors_list,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.Name1.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.Description1.setText(arrayList.get(position).getDescription());
        Picasso.with(holder.Pic1.getContext()).load(Uri.parse(arrayList.get(position).getPic())).into(holder.Pic1);

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        TextView Name1;
        TextView Description1;
        ImageView Pic1;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            Name1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            Description1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            Pic1  = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pic);

        }
    }


}
```

My app works right but just when i fetch data from local services.

Comment: Change the file extension name "contactinfo.php" to "contactinfo.json" then try hope it will work.

Comment: if I change the extension file.I will not have any output.i use php servise's

Comment: @pedramshabani did you tried to change `Request.Method.POST` to get method?

Comment: i did  and  no  result again...:-(

Comment: I didn't find any problem in your code except that `BackgrundTask.getList()` returning `arrayList`, Could you please check if it is returning **blank** `ArrayList` which is assigned to your `RecyclerView Adapter` and mayBe the reason for no data getting displayed

Comment: @pedramshabani is ` Log.d("TAG67", response.toString()); ` printing/writing expected response in console ?

Comment: Mahmood Sanjrani:it is my consol:  when run app in emalator ----->>>      D/TAG67: [{"Name":"naseri","Pic":"http:\/\/www.viratebco.com\/phpme\/3\/actor3.jpg","Description":"در کل شرکت آمازون به‌دنبال ورود به‌ بخش‌های مختلفی از تجارت الکترونیک است و همچنین در زمینه به‌خدمت گرفتن دیگر شرکت‌ها و فروشگاه‌های اینترنتی هم دریغ نمی‌کند. "},{"Name":"soltani","Pic":"http:\/\/www.viratebco.com\/phpme\/3\/actor.jpg","Description":"gg"},{"Name":"shabnai","Pic":"http:\/\/www.viratebco.com\/phpme\/3\/actor4.jpg","Description":"hh"}]

Comment: D/Volley: [175] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://www.viratebco.com/phpme/3/1.php 0xc4a84e57 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=5462], [size=579], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]

Comment: – Firoz Memon::I am guessing.my RecyclerView Adapter have not any problem because when i use Address Local (example:http://192.168.1.4/android/contactinfo.php))my app Works fine.

Comment: @pedramshabani I have updated my answer. which should resolve your problem.

Comment: @pedramshabani Does the answer solve your question? Please [**See this image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

> I checked your code everything was at it's place except
>   listener.onReponseReceive(arrayList); as mentioned in my answer it
>   should be right after where while loop ends. Now your recyclerview is
>   displaying items

Update:

> The reason You are not getting the list in your recyclerview is
>   because it takes some time to fetch response from webserver and your
>   list get return earlier. In order to Resolve this, Try this

Create an Interface

```
    public interface WebResponseListener{
     void onReponseReceive(ArrayList <Contact_actors_list> list);
   }
```

In your BackgrundTask declare a variable of this interface

```
WebResponseListener listener;
public BackgrundTask (Context context,WebResponseListener listener)
    {
       this.listener = listener
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Make your getList() return void and do the following changes

```
 public void getList(){
//Where your while condition ends
//add following line
  listener.onReponseReceived(arrayList);
    -----
}
```

IN actorsList class
Make yout actorList class implements the inferface as

```
public class actorsList extends AppCompatActivity implements WebResponseListener
```

replace the following lines

```
BackgrundTask backgroundTask = new BackgrundTask(actorsList.this); 
 arrayList = backgroundTask.getList();
```

with

```
BackgrundTask backgroundTask = new BackgrundTask(this,this); 
arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new RecyclerAdapterActorsList(arrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
backgroundTask.getList();
```

Add the following method in your  actorsList class

```
public void onReponseReceive(ArrayList <Contact_actors_list> list){
    actorsList.this.arrayList.addAll(list);
    actorsList.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

[image: Recyclerview]

Comment: thank you Sahil Manchanda .now i have fetal error::->>> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference

Comment: at ir.gitta.www.successsecrets.actorsList.onReponseReceive(actorsList.java:71)
  at ir.gitta.www.successsecrets.BackgrundTask.getList(BackgrundTask.java:98) at ir.gitta.www.successsecrets.actorsList.onCreate(actorsList.java:62)

Comment: @pedramshabani Answer Updated. NullPointerException error occured because adapter was not initialized before calling getList() method.

Comment: Sahil Manchanda :really thank you so much but  actorList Does not show anything still.

Comment: Can you email me the project so that i can check. if possible or let me create a dummy project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153540/discussion-between-sahil-manchanda-and-pedram-shabani).