# Parse nested Json array in Android using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

this is my JSON - https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken.

I am trying to get only the 'label' which is the food name and 'image' which is food photo.

This is my code below.

```
JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()

    {


        @Override
        public void onResponse( JSONObject response) {

            try {;

               JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("hits");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String recipe = jsonObject.optString("recipe");
                    String name = jsonObject.optString("label");
                    String label = jsonObject.optString("image");

                    txtDisplay.setText(recipe + name + label);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volley", "Error");
        }
    });

    queue.add(obreq);
}
```

}

This code returns me the JSON data, but it returns all the data.

Can anyone please provide sample code so that it returns specific values only.

Thanks

Comment: Read this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897838/receiving-data-from-web-server-doesnt-work-volley-library-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small function that extracts only what is needed i.e **label** and **image** into `List<FoodModel>` object which can be used in list view or recyclerview to display items.

```
 private List<FoodModel> getFoodList(String json) throws JSONException {
    List<FoodModel> foodModels = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("hits");
    for (int count = 0; count < jsonArray.length(); count++) {
        JSONObject innerObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
        JSONObject recipe = innerObject.getJSONObject("recipe");
        FoodModel foodModel = new FoodModel();
        foodModel.setImage(recipe.getString("label"));
        foodModel.setLabel(recipe.getString("label"));
        foodModels.add(foodModel);
    }
    return foodModels;
}
```

**FoodModel** goes here

```
 public class FoodModel {

    private String label;
    private String image;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(final String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(final String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```